# Custom CA Certificate in Charles without a password

Tags: debugging, charles-proxy

I'm using the excellent [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy to make web debugging easier. I'm using it's SSL proxying abilities, and have installed the [generic CA Certificate](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) that it comes bundled with. While this works, it's insecure because as long as my browser trusts this certificate, I am vulnerable to a MIM attack.

I'm trying to use OpenSSL to create a "Custom CA Certificate" since Charles allows to fix this. These are the steps I'm following:

```
NAME=daaku-ca
openssl genrsa -out $NAME.key 1024
openssl req -new -key $NAME.key -out $NAME.csr
openssl x509 -days 3650 -signkey $NAME.key -in $NAME.csr -req -out $NAME.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out $NAME.pfx -inkey $NAME.key -in $NAME.crt
```

Following these steps I end up with a *Self signed root certificate* `$NAME.crt` that I successfully imported into my Mac OS X keychain. And while the `$NAME.pfx` in Charles works and is being correctly used if I enter a password for it, it does not work if there's no password.

My question is how do I generate a certificate that works in Charles and does not need a password.

Comment: Found some more information which likely explains it: http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=1497&user=guest&pass=guest -- still not sure how I can work around it. Maybe `keytool` can be used instead?

Answer (score 7):

I blogged about how to use a Custom SSL Certificate with Charles and in the last section I address the problem of having to type in the password every time Charles launches.

http://codeblog.shape.dk/blog/2014/01/06/custom-ssl-certificate-with-charles-web-proxy/

Comment: Nice - haven't tried it, but seems like an excellent workaround!

Answer (score 3):

Since Charles 3.10 came out this is not an issue anymore since each installation generates its own certificate. So even if you trust the Charles-generated Certificate, you won't be susceptible to MIM attacks by other Charles users.

[Per version 3.10 release notes:](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/)

> Version 3.10 21 March 2015
>
> Major new features, improvements and bug fixes.
>
> SSL changes
>
> SSL certificate root certificate change to generate a unique
>   certificate for each installation of Charles (see SSL Proxying in the
>   Help menu) SSL Proxying now has its own settings menu item in the
>   Proxy menu Please note that these changes will affect the way you
>   currently use Charles for SSL Proxying. You will need to install and
>   trust a new certificate, which will be automatically generated for
>   you. You can install that certificate on your computer using the
>   options in the Help menu, under SSL Proxying. You can also export the
>   certificate, to send to other systems, or browse to download the
>   certificate to install on mobile devices such as iPhones.